# Subir archivos a partir de un formulario input tipo file

Tags: php, html, wordpress, fileupload

me surge una duda y es cómo poder subir más de un archivo, ya que solo puedo subir uno. Me gustaria que pudiese coger mas de un fichero igual que subirlo, y cuando le de en aceptar se suban directamente sin tener que darle al botón enviar.

**PHP**

```
   if(isset($_FILES['upload-file'])) {
        global $wp_filesystem;
        WP_Filesystem();

        $name_file = $_FILES['upload-file']['name'];
        $tmp_name = $_FILES['upload-file']['tmp_name'];
        $allow_extensions = ['xls', 'xlsx','pdf','csv'];

        // File type validation
        $path_parts = pathinfo($name_file);
        $ext = $path_parts['extension'];

        if ( ! in_array($ext, $allow_extensions) ) {
            echo "Error - File type not allowed";
            return;
        }

    global $current_user; wp_get_current_user();
    $username = $current_user->user_login;
        $content_directory = $wp_filesystem->wp_content_dir() . "uploads/archivos-subidos/$username/";
        $wp_filesystem->mkdir( $content_directory );

        if( move_uploaded_file( $tmp_name, $content_directory . " " . $name_file ) ) {
            echo "<p style='border: 2px solid green; color:green; padding-left: 10px;'>FICHERO SUBIDO CORRECTAMENTE</p>";
        } else {
                echo "<p style='border: 2px solid red; color:red;'>FICHERO NO SUBIDO CORRECTAMENTE</p>";
        }
    }
```

**HTML**

```
  <label for="upload-file">  <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
          <input name="upload-file" type="file" id="upload-file" />
          <input type="submit" value="Enviar archivo" />
```

Comment: Pistas: Agrega el atributo `multiple` al campo y corchetes al nombre `name="upload-file[]"` para que sea tratado como arreglo. Con el evento `onchange` puedes hacer que el formulario se envíe en cuanto se seleccionen los archivos. Finalmente, en PHP cada atributo de `$_FILES['uploaded-file']` va a ser un arreglo. Más info en la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.multiple.php)

Comment: ¿Tu input está en un `form`? ¿Ha sido declarado ese `form` como `multipart`? Si es así no deberías tener ningún problema en subir múltiples archivos. En cuanto a subirlos automáticamente, puedes usar Javascript y lanzar el envío de los archivos desde el evento `on change` del `input` que los recoge, usando preferiblemnte `FormData`.